# Failed to Docker login to JFrog Artifactory running in a Docker

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I following the steps in section of **Docker Installation**" to get JFrog Artifactory (version 4.160 rev 40364) running in a Docker on Linux Mint fine and I able to access my instance JFrog Artifactory from Chrome browser at: http://SERVER_HOSTNAME:8082/ui/. Please see the URL

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation

On my Virtual server running Linux where I Installed JFrog Artifactory and Docker
I have my host file to contains
 docker-virtual.art.local docker-dev-local2.art.local docker-prod-local2.art.local

Also I created and edit /etc/default/docker file to contains
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry docker-virtual.art.local --insecure-registry docker-dev-local2.art.local --insecure-registry docker-prod-local2.art.local --insecure-registry docker-remote.art.local"

My problem is when I tried to
**docker login docker-virtual.art.local**
or
**docker push docker-virtual.art.local/hello-world**

I get errors of
**response from daemon: Get https://docker-virtual.art.local/v2/: Gateway Timeout**
or

**Get https://docker-virtual.art.local/v2/: Gateway Timeout**

Can you please let know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is that Artifactory is installed as a Docker container which means that this Artifactory's conatainer's IP is different from the localhost(Linux server). I assume that the host file is edited for the localhost and not for the container's IP. Make sure that the container's IP can be accessed over the Linux server which should be accessible and then change the host file accordingly. Provided this Gateway timeout happens when there is no response from the server and client times out and I believe that the IPs play a significant role here since Artifactory is running as docker container.

Comment: NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
0d0fc3799bc8        bridge              bridge              local
50cf3e2b3f4a        host                host                local
ed6ca01522f1        none                null                local

Comment: docker network inspect -f '{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Subnet}}{{end}}'  0d0fc3799bc8
172.17.0.0/16

Comment: I do not see the Jfrog docker IP address when I did docker network ls

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can get JFrog Container;s IP ?